# Is (Azure) DataCache.Increment thread safe?

Tags: caching, azure, azure-caching

Does anybody know if [DataCache.Increment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIbrary/jj613635.aspx) is thread safe? (I.e. can I call it simultaneously in parallel on different machines and/or threads without worrying about the calls overwriting each other?)

The documentation doesn't mention anything about Thread Safety even though I'm guessing the methods is there just for this reason. But still, I don't want to rely on assumption when building my app.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure cache handles concurrency internally through locking in this case. Unfortunately I can't back this up with a link, just past experience as we currently use this feature in production.

To be doubly sure you can always write a quick worker role that increments in parallel and then verifies the returned Int64.

Comment: Thanks! I've already tested it and it seems to work just as expected. But it's a quite a lot of work to change to version-aware methods if it turns out that it isn't working as expected later on.

Answer (score 0):

The API is meant to be thread safe (internal locking ensures all of this).